# Routes inside Routes EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm aware that ember doesn't support this, as per http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ : "You cannot nest routes, but you can nest resources"

But what I'm trying to do seems reasonable, so I'm assuming there's support for this somewhere.

The goal here is to have a structure like this:

```
this.resource('project', { path: '/project/:project_id' }, function(){

      this.route('manage', function(){
          this.route('settings');
          this.route('team');
          this.route('notifications');
          /* etc */
      });

 });
```

In words, I'd like to have a "manage" section with subsections for the things you can manage, all of which referencing my "project" instance.

I could do this:

```
this.resource('project', { path: '/project/:project_id' }, function(){

      this.route('manage.settings',{path : '/manage/settings'});
      this.route('manage.team',{path : '/manage/team'});
      /*etc*/

});
```

But where this fails is:

1. I can't share a nav between resource subsections (i.e have a manage template with an outlet that is populated by the sub route)
2. My settings.hbs doesn't isn't accessing the parent resource (I'm sure this is fixed inside the router config's "model" or "setupController" hooks, I'm just not sure which / how)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a nested resource?

```
this.resource('project', { path: '/project/:project_id' }, function(){
  this.resource('manage', function(){
      this.route('settings');
      this.route('team');
      this.route('notifications');
      /* etc */
  });
});
```

This is not so different from the post/comments resources described in the ember guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources

> I'd like to have a "manage" section with subsections for the things you can manage, all of which referencing my "project" instance.

Ok. So using nested-resources approach you will have a `manage.hbs` template. To reference the project instance from the manage section or any of the subsections just use `needs` like this:

```
App.ManageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: "project",
  projectBinding: "controllers.project"
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/ for more detail.

Comment: I think you are right about using a resource, but your reco doesn't fly with this line from the same page you are referencing:

"NOTE: You should use this.resource for URLs that represent a noun, and this.route for URLs that represent adjectives or verbs modifying those nouns."

Perhaps the solution is to have a route called "manage" and then 3 resources under it "settings" (a noun) "team" (a noun) etc.

If I do this, though, I need models for each of those (not a bad thing), but I'm confused at how those models will be populated from the server and relate to the parent resource.

Comment: i think of it like resource=a-thing and route=something-to-do-with-that-thing. Either way seems like the issue is the word manage, which is clearly not a `thing`. managedProject (the thing) has settings, a team and notifications. Then you have `App.ManagedProjectSettings`, etc. which seems like what you are going for. FWIW i think you might be reading too much into this. Routes and resources can both be associated with models. And no matter what you chose it has nothing to do with how models are populated from the server and relate to one another.

Comment: I think this is the correct way to think about it - ManagedProject would be the *thing* and essentially just a proxy for the parent.